# Rails db:migrate fails with SQL error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

rake db:migrate is failing on my production server, the error is:

`Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'String' at line 1: 'ALTER TABLE looks' ADD 'code' String`

My migration code is:

```
class AddCodeToLook < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :looks, :code, :String #failing line
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :looks, :code
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `:string` and not `:String`

Comment: Oh, man I didn't even noticed, strangely it worked on sqlite. Thank you so much, I'm really grateful!

Comment: Sometimes you can bang your head against these tiny little mistakes for ages and you either figure it out eventually, or someone else spots it instantly :P

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's just a typo, but `:String` should be `:string` in your add_column line.

When you add a column like this, you can use the built-in rails generator to handle the grunt work:

```
rails g migration AddCodeToLook code:string
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [this official Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html), it looks like the issue is that you're not using the right casing for the data type. You should be using `:string`.

```
class AddCodeToLook < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :looks, :code, :string
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :looks, :code
  end
end
```